# SQL count query with join on same table

Tags: sql, join

Sorry in advance for this question if the solution should be obvious. I have searched but not found a solution yet.

I have an Orders table that includes 2 columns: CustID and ProductBrand.
ProductBrand is the make of the item ordered, e.g. Sony, HP, Dell, etc.

I want to get the list of customers that have ordered at least 10 items with ProductBrand=Sony but less than 5 items with ProductBrand=HP.

Can I do this with something along these lines?

```
SELECT o1.CustID
FROM Orders o1 HAVING COUNT(o1.ProductBrand="Sony") >= 10
INNER JOIN Orders o2 ON o1.CustID = o2.CustID
HAVING COUNT(o2.ProductBrand="HP") < 5;
```

Comment: what was your result from query ?..

Comment: The query I gave in the description is actually rejected by the SQL parser. I just provided it to give some details of what I was trying to do. Sorry if I did not make that clear.

Answer (score 4):

You would do this without a self-join, just aggregation:

```
select o.custid
from orders o
group by o.custid
having sum(case when o.ProductBrand = 'Sony' then 1 else 0 end) >= 10 and
       sum(case when o.ProductBrand = 'HP' then 1 else 0 end) < 5;
```

In MySQL, you can simplify this by removing the `case`:

```
select o.custid
from orders o
group by o.custid
having sum(o.ProductBrand = 'Sony') >= 10 and
       sum(o.ProductBrand = 'HP') < 5;
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. Now that I see it, it looks simple and obvious, but I would not have known about that without a hint. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Setup fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (cust INT, brand VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3, 'Sony')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3, 'Hp')
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3, 'Hp')
```

Query

Method 1

```
select 
    sony.custId 
from 
    (select cust as custId, Brand, count(*) as count 
     from orders 
     where Brand = 'Sony' 
     group by cust, brand) Sony 
         inner join 
     (select cust as custId, Brand, count(*) as count 
      from orders 
      where Brand = 'Hp' 
      group by cust, brand) Hp 
          on sony.custId = hp.CustId 
Where 
    sony.count > 2 and 
    hp.count < 5
```

This is good for you to understand relation. Here is another way

Method 2

```
select cust  
from orders 
group by cust, brand
having  count(case brand when 'Sony' then 'x' end) > 2 and 
        count(case brand when 'Hp' then 'x' end) < 5
```

The time is about the same - sure it will vary based on amount of data, indexes, etc. Use Sql fiddle to check execution plan. Looks like in first method more things are going on. But doesn't mean that when you use in production, it will be much worse.

Comment: What a useful tool! I was looking for something like that - finding out about Fiddle was, by itself, worth this post. With your method 1 I see now how the inner join syntax needs to be - I figured there must be some way to specify the separate queries and then join them with count comparisons but couldn't find examples for problems similar to mine. T.S., I thank you for your generosity in taking the time to provide a solution - hope to be able to do the same for someone else as you have done for me.